# Is there any way to make markdown tables sortable?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I'd like to write my table in markdown text, but allow it to be sortable on github after its been rendered(simple asc/desc sorting by clicking on the column header.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Table sorting is only possible with JavaScript. However, GitHub does not provide their own table sorting script and for security reasons do not allow users to include scripts on their pages. So, not, this is not possible. If you want table sorting, you need to host your content elsewhere.

Answer (score 40):

Table sort is not supported in Github flavored markdown but one alternative is to use user script such as [Github Sort Content](https://github.com/Mottie/GitHub-userscripts/wiki/GitHub-sort-content)

It's very easy to install, for instance from Chrome :

- install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)
- install [Github Sort Content](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/21373-github-sort-content) from Greasyfork

Then tables from `github.com` markdown pages can be sorted like :

[image]

Comment: Of course, only the person who installs the local browser plugin will be able to use the feature. It won't be available to everyone.

Comment: This wouldn't be useful, I need all the readers of my table to have it sortable.

Comment: Do these plugins or simiilar ones work for Azure wiki markdown pages?

Answer (score 9):

A possible alternative is offered with [GitLab 15.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/09/22/gitlab-15-4-released/#sortable-filterable-data-driven-tables-in-markdown) (September 2022):

> ### Sortable, filterable data-driven tables in Markdown
>
> Working with tables in Markdown can be a bit cumbersome. Not only is it difficult to figure out the correct number of pipes and empty cells, but the table output is static when you save your document. If you have to sort the table by the third column in an ascending order, you end up rewriting the whole thing.
>
> Now you can insert data-driven tables using JSON syntax as follows:
>
> In the rendered table, you can also enable:
>
> - Sorting for specific fields using `"sortable": true`
> - Dynamic filtering of data using `"filter" : true`
>
> Now it’s as simple as a click when you have to re-sort that 100-row table and as easy as a web search when you have to find that one issue reference lost in a sea of nearly identical URLs.
>
> [image: GitLab sortable table]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#json) and [Merge Request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/86353).

Answer (score 1):

There are some Chrome plugins that do this, including [HTML Table Auto Sort](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-table-auto-sort/bpgbkjehkeffmmjfmdlmjjlffgkdcljp) that I've used that toggles ascending/descending sort when clicking on a column header.